# file upload in asp.net mvc 4 razor

Tags: c#, file-upload, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using **ASP .Net MVC 4.0** and **VS10**. I am a newbie in web application.

I have designed a page with html razor view. Here is some code of **Index.cshtml**:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "BAP Automation";
}
@section featured {
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
                <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
            </hgroup>
            <form action="Index">
            <table>              **//EDITED BELLOW**
                <tr><form action="" method="post">
                    <td>Upload Excel File: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="NAMEtxtFileName"/></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="Upload" id="IDbtnUpload" name="NAMEbtnUpload"/></td>
                    </form>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Company Name: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" /></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td align="right"><input type="submit" value="Process" /></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
}
```

I am trying to upload an excel file in **NAMEbtnUpload**'s click event. clicking on this button we will be in this page, just a file upload dialog will open and selecting the file, the file location will be shown in the **NAMEtxtFileName** textbox.

**EDIT 1:**

I have written some code from the suggested code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase NAMEbtnUpload)
    {
        if (NAMEbtnUpload.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(NAMEbtnUpload.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Given Excel's"), fileName);
            NAMEbtnUpload.SaveAs(path);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

but this shows following error:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

**The resource cannot be found.** 
**Description**: **HTTP 404**. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

**Requested URL:** /

Comment: Have you configured routing in your RouteConfig ?

Comment: Here's an inline link that might help you (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680629/mvc-4-razor-file-upload).

Answer (score 14):

Try adding the "EncType" attribute to your form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ACTION", "CONTROLLER", FormMethod.Post, new { EncType="multipart/form-data"})){
  //FORM MARKUP HERE
}
```

Comment: What would that look like for a partial view that would be reused across multiple controllers?

Answer (score 10):

Phil Haack shows you how to handle file uploads with his blog post [Uploading a File (Or Files) With ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx).

There is quite a bit of stuff you are missing so reading that post will get you further than any answer here.

** UPDATE FOR EDIT 1 **

A couple issues

1. `<form action="index" >`  - this should be `<form action="/ControllerName/Index">`
2. You have multiple form tags that are nested.  You can have multiple form tags but they can't be nested.  In your case your only need one.  Most of the time you only need 1.
3. `<input type="button" value="Upload" id="IDbtnUpload" name="NAMEbtnUpload"/>` should be

It is more conventional to use `@using(Html.BeginForm())` as opposed to manually writing form tags. See below.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index"))
{
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Upload Excel File: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="NAMEtxtFileName"/></td>
        <td><input type="file" id="IDbtnUpload" name="NAMEbtnUpload"/></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Company Name: </td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right"><input type="submit" value="Process" /></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
}
```

Comment: i have read this. but facing problem. Here, my question has been edited. please take a look.

Answer (score 4):

> clicking on [the upload] button we will be in this page, just a file upload dialog will open and selecting the file, the file location will be shown in the NAMEtxtFileName textbox.

That is not possible because a file upload element is not accessible programatically, anymore. "Back in the days" it was, and malicious sites silently uploaded sensitive information by setting the file upload control's value to well known password file locations and so on.

You'll just have to put an `<input type="file" />` on your form and handle the upload serverside, as suggested in the link on @Bretts answer.

Comment: i have to redirect to another page? by action="" and method="post"?

Comment: just to know, input type file must have a name attribute, instead file was not uploaded (tested on chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Set the name of file control in controller class.
for example in above code

```
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase NAMEbtnUpload)
```

change NAMEbtnUpload to NAMEtxtFileName 
this resolve your problem.