# MVC 4 Razor File Upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am new to MVC 4 and I am trying to implement File Upload Control in
my website. I am not able to find the mistake.I am getting a null
value in my file.

Controller:

```
public class UploadController : BaseController
    {
        public ActionResult UploadDocument()
        {
            return View();
        }

       [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
       {
           if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
           {
               var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
               var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), fileName);
               file.SaveAs(path);
           }

           return RedirectToAction("UploadDocument");
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
    <input type="file" name="FileUpload" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [File Upload ASP.NET MVC 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc-3-0)

Comment: you just have to change public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file) <input type="file" name="FileUpload" />

Comment: check out my Implementation here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40990080/4251431

Comment: Missing out the `enctype` on the form cost me an hour

Comment: Where is the connection between the Upload() method and the button. Should there be an onClick event? New to asp.net I am

Answer (score 345, accepted):

The `Upload` method's `HttpPostedFileBase` parameter must have the same name as the the `file input`.

So just change the input to this:

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

Also, you could find the files in `Request.Files`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload()
{
     if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
     {
         var file = Request.Files[0];

         if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
         {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
         }
     }

     return RedirectToAction("UploadDocument");
 }
```

Comment: won't it through `Index out of bounds` exception in case there is no file in the `Request.Files` collection..?

Comment: Actually it will throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, but your are right, i updated

Comment: Remember that the parameters of the Html.BeginForm are the action name and the controller name (without the 'controller' postfix. For instance: Home instead of HomeController). Another important thing is to not include the <form> tag inside, because is the BeginForm that opens the tag

Comment: In other words - Your view model property name must match that of the input type name. If your `viewmodel` property is named `AgentPhoto` then you must have the following on your view: `<input type="file" name="AgentPhoto"/>`

Comment: `var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), fileName);`, the class "Server" not found, which package use?

Comment: Where is the connection between the Upload() method and the button. Should there be an onClick event? New to asp.net I am

Comment: To ensure the names match, I do it this way:
<input type="file" name="@Html.IdFor(m => m.File)" />

Answer (score 66):

Clarifying it.
Model:

```
public class ContactUsModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }             
    public string LastName { get; set; }              
    public string Email { get; set; }                 
    public string Phone { get; set; }                 
    public HttpPostedFileBase attachment { get; set; }
```

Post Action

```
public virtual ActionResult ContactUs(ContactUsModel Model)
{
 if (Model.attachment.HasFile())
 {
   //save the file

   //Send it as an attachment 
    Attachment messageAttachment = new Attachment(Model.attachment.InputStream,       Model.attachment.FileName);
  }
}
```

Finally the Extension method for checking the hasFile

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AtlanticCMS.Web.Common
{
     public static class ExtensionMethods 
     {
         public static bool HasFile(this HttpPostedFileBase file)
         {
             return file != null && file.ContentLength > 0;
         }        
     }
 }
```

Comment: public HttpPostedFileBase attachment { get; set; }/ attachment is not an identify

Comment: I think Cola is referring to the Attachment type not being defined.

Comment: View could be used as described by user2028367. Actually i forgot to include new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" } in Html.BeginForm part, so was unable to view the file in my action. Great answer. +1 for showing in Model class and Extension method.

Comment: @BishoyHanna How I put, on my form, the attachment. For the other values razor provide to us a simple syntax, but how I do it for this file?

Comment: Sorry @DenisV, can you clarify  ?

Comment: @BishoyHanna, on our form, if we want a textfileld using the model, we put this code: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AssetName)` and for our file input? `<input type="file" name="file"` don't assign it to the model

Comment: @BishoyHanna Good approach, but did not worked for me. May it be related to using AJAX? If so, which approach is better for posting multiple files to Controler in ASP.NET MVC5? Request.Files or this approach if it can works for AJAX of course.

Comment: hi, @ClintEastwood, that post was for uploading one file, I searched online for something that matches multiple uploads (for you) and found that one which I think would work.
Again, its model based which is not using "Request.Files"

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210413/multiple-file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 17):

View Page

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionmethodName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formid" }))
 { 
   <input type="file" name="file" />
   <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="save" id="btnid" />
 }
```

script file

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnid", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var fileOptions = {
            success: res,
            dataType: "json"
        }
        $("#formid").ajaxSubmit(fileOptions);
    });
```

In Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

    }
```

Comment: I agree with @Muflix , you don't need `AJAX` here. `Html.BeginForm` does the job already.
AJAX is only needed if you don't want a redirect to the `<form action=LINK>`

Comment: Ajax is better for larger files since it allows you to enhance the user experience.

Answer (score 6):

you just have to change the name of your input filed because same name is required in parameter and input field name
just replace this line Your code working fine

```
 <input type="file" name="file" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, better way is use *HttpPostedFileBase* in your controller or API. After this you can simple detect size, type etc.

File properties you can find here:

[MVC3 How to check if HttpPostedFileBase is an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120135/mvc3-how-to-check-if-httppostedfilebase-is-an-image)

For example ImageApi:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/image")]  
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)  
{  
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)  
        try 
        {  
            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"),  
               Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));

            file.SaveAs(path);  
            ViewBag.Message = "Your message for success";  
        }  
        catch (Exception ex)  
        {  
            ViewBag.Message = "ERROR:" + ex.Message.ToString();  
        }  
    else 
    {  
        ViewBag.Message = "Please select file";  
    }  
    return View();  
}
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Better than what? The OP is already using `HttpPostedFileBase`.