# Razor upload file returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, file-upload

I have some issue for my c# code for upload some file...in controller file detect null.

My html code

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "UploadHistory",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="btnSubmit" />
}
```

and this code for my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
    {
        // Verify that the user selected a file
        if (uploadFile != null && uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            // extract only the fielname
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName);
            // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
            uploadFile.SaveAs(path);
        }
        // redirect back to the index action to show the form once again
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Any ideas why my upload file detect null?? i use C# mvc 4 and razor thank you.

[SOLVED]
Just error in javascript method post.

Comment: The code looks absolutely fine. Infact i've tested your code on my machine and able to recieve the file at the controller end. Can you check if you've recieved file through `Request.Files`

Comment: in my controller uploadFile is null how to through use request.files ??

Comment: press Shift+F9 in debuggin mode and enter `Request.Files.Count`. If you've recieved a file you should see the count as 1.

Comment: my result is 0.. how to fix it..

Comment: Can you cross check if you're using the correct action and correct controller. If it still doesn't work, take a fresh controller and action and copy the code in this post and paste appropriately and give it a try.

Comment: in upload file maybe i missing some setting do you know that thing ??

Comment: I don't find any clue and issues with the code. Have you tried a fresh copy of the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this link

[Possible copy of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680629/mvc-4-razor-file-upload)

In short

Use

`public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)`

Also change

`<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />`

to

`<input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" />`

Comment: still return null i already see that link but still not work for my issues

Comment: are you passing HttpPostedFileBase as parameter or your class uploadFile?

Comment: i already change my code but still not work see the question again

Comment: the code you have uploaded here is working fine in my machine

Comment: ohhh can i missing some setting or etc??

Comment: we can have a teamviewer if required.

Comment: we code already working now,,error because conflict javascript method post. thank's

Answer (score 2):

The following should work for you:

**Model**

```
public class UploadFileModel 
{
    public UploadFileModel()
    {
        Files = new List<HttpPostedFileBase>();
    }

    public List<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }

}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
 Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Files.Files, new { type = "file", name = "Files" })
 <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="btnSubmit" />
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(UploadFileModel model)
{
    var file = model.Files[0];
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: the type or namespace name HttpPostedFileBase couldn't be found , it's mean i missing something..how to fix it

Comment: Include Namespace:  `System.Web`

Comment: still same error the type or namespace name HttpPostedFileBase couldn't be found.. i already add using System.Web;

Comment: Did you added in the Model Class?

Comment: ya in 

public class UploadFileModel file

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure model binding works in this scenario. Either you need to use `HttpPostedFileBase` as a parameter to the controller action or you need to use `Request.Files` option.

Using Request.Files option.

```
foreach (string file in Request.Files)
{
   HttpPostedFile hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFile;
   if (hpf.ContentLength == 0)
      continue;
   string savedFileName = Path.Combine(
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, 
      Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
   hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName);
}
```

EDIT : Here I found a blog which uses similar scenario (Model binding). It may help you - http://cpratt.co/file-uploads-in-asp-net-mvc-with-view-models/

Comment: can you give example about request.files

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) 
        {

            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");        
    }
```

mainly use `HttpPostedFileBase` in your parameter