# How to Upload file In MVC + Umbraco 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, umbraco, umbraco7

I am new to MVC and need help to upload File , I am using umbraco. 7.2.1
I am trying to send mail with mail with attachment
Following is my code for the same.
Partial View ==>name  Contact

```
 using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<ContactVController>("HandleContactSubmit"))   
    {
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)<br />
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)<br />
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)<br />

       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)<br />
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)<br />
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)<br />
          <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
        <p>
           <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
       </p>
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class ContactVModel  
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase attachment { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class ContactVController : SurfaceController
    {
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult HandleContactSubmit(ContactVModel model)
        {
,.......... ...... ....

  ,.......... ...... ....  

    MailBody + = model.Name ;
MailBody + = model.Email;

SendMail( MailBody )
}
```

But I do not know access model.attachment , How can I do so to send mail with attachment (the file which is uploaded ) (As I am able to acces Name, Email, etc.)
I have referred following post but I could not able to access attachment

[MVC 4 Razor File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680629/mvc-4-razor-file-upload)

but I could not make it out

Comment: you need to name the input field the same as the property you want it to be bound to, so change it from "file" to "attachment".

Comment: You mean some thing like this ? <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" />

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: best you put it into an answer so he can accept it ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Change the input from

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
```

to

```
<input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" />
```

So the property in the model matches the input field.

I'm currently using the following:

```
In the cshtml file:
@Html.UploadFor(model=> model.Attachment)

static public class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString UploadFor<TSource, TResult>(this HtmlHelper<TSource> html, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> propertyExpression)
    {
        var memberName = Reflection.GetPropertyName(propertyExpression);
        return new HtmlString($"<input type=\"file\" name=\"{memberName}\" id=\"{memberName}\">");
    }
}

class Reflection
{
    public static string GetPropertyName<TSource, TResult>(Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> propertyExpression)
    {
        return (propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
    }
}
```