# Catch incoming files from another server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Situation :

- An application sends periodically a file to an endpoint (i can change the endpoint)
- I have an ASP.NET MVC application that needs to capture the files and do some processing

Question :
 - What kind of method do I use to capture all the files?

```
1. Some kind of listener
2 .public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
3. ...???
```

Comment: What do you mean "capture all the files"? If you are asking how to upload files to MVC, did you search for any existing answers?

Comment: There are multiple SO questions about uploading files, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680629/mvc-4-razor-file-upload) and articles like [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/). Should this question be closed as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here 
http://blog.anthonybaker.me/2013/06/how-to-implement-file-upload-restful.html

I just needed to use the Request.Files from HttpRequestBase (System.Web.Mvc.Controller class)