# How to upload multiple files with jQuery.filer plugin in ASP.NET MVC 5 using View Models

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am using [jQuery.filer](http://filer.grandesign.md/) on a `FileUpload` control in an `MVC5` project and I want to post multiple files from `View` to `Controller` using `ViewModel`. Normally I have used some approach as `AJAX` and `Request.Files[n]` but I want to use `ViewModel` as I already pass it to the Controller. I followed a good example [File Uploads in ASP.NET MVC with View Models](http://cpratt.co/file-uploads-in-asp-net-mvc-with-view-models/) by `@ChrisPratt`, but he does not talk about multiple uploads and there are some problems related to file upload control in `MVC5`. So, could you please inform me what changes should be made in order to pass multiple file upload from `View` to `Controller` and get these multiple files in a `foreach` loop.

***View:***

```
@model ExperimentViewModel
<input type="file" name="FileUpload" id="filer_input" multiple="multiple" >

<!-- or -->
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FileUpload, new { type = "file" , id="filer_input"})

<script>
    $('#filer_input').filer({
        limit: null,
        maxSize: null,
        extensions: null,
        uploadFile: {
            url: //URL to which the request is sent {String}
            data: //Data to be sent to the server {Object}
            type: 'POST', //The type of request {String}
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data', //Request enctype {String}
        }
    )};

    function create(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var formdata = new FormData($('#frmCreate').get(0)); 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Experiment")',
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: formdata,         
            processData: false, 
            contentType: false
        });
    };
<script>
```

***ViewModel:***

```
public class ExperimentViewModel
{
    //code omitted for brevity

    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload { get; set; }
}
```

***Controller:***

```
public JsonResult Insert([Bind(Exclude = null)] ExperimentViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //I have no idea how to retrieve the files.Count(), files in an IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>
        var files = model.FileUpload;
        if(files != null && files.Count() > 0)
        {
            //???
        }           
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The property needs to be `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> FileUpload` to accept multiple files (and note it would need to be `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FileUpload, new { type = "file", multiple = "multiple" })` to add the `multiple` attribute)

Comment: It can passed to the Controller. On the other hand, I use [jQuery.filer](http://filer.grandesign.md/#demos) and I have to give an id to the FileUploader as **filer_input** in order to use [jQuery.filer](http://filer.grandesign.md/#demos). However, when using the id as "filer_input" or changing "FileUpload" property name to "filer_input" the model data pass as null to the Controller (model.FileUpload or model.filer_input). When looking at the Network panel of Firebug, I see that the model data pass as **Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FileUpload[]"; filename="test.xlsx"** (added "[]") >>>

Comment: >>> Do you have any idea why the data cannot be passed to the Controller when using I use [jQuery.filer](http://filer.grandesign.md/#demos)? Do I have to add the data to AJAX post?

Comment: Never seen that plugin before. Will have a look a bit later.

Comment: Thanks, you might have  a look at the parameter explanations on https://github.com/avral/jquery.filer

Comment: On the other hand, should I add the file data to the **FormData()** in AJAX as shown on [Simple File Uploads Using jQuery & AJAX](https://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax)?

Comment: `var formdata = new FormData($('#frmCreate').get(0));` will correctly serialize the files. There is no need to append them again.

Comment: I debug the formdata but cannot see the form values in Developer Tools, even if the values except from FileUpload can be passed and seen on the Controller. How can I debug the problem? I think there is no mistake regarding to the AJAX method that I had already used successfully before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125226/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-clint-eastwood).

Comment: @StephenMuecke **SOLVED!..** Many thanks for your help... I posted the result as answer so that other people can also benefit from your answer. Regards...

Answer (score 2):

=============================== **S O L V E D** ================================

Here is the solution by **@StephenMuecke**. Many thanks for his huge help...

***View:***

```
@model ExperimentViewModel

//Change 1
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FileUpload, new { type = "file", multiple = "multiple" })

<script>        
    function create(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        //Change 2 : Because jquery.filer adds "[]" to the Name parameter!!!
        $('#FileUpload').attr('name', 'FileUpload');

        var formdata = new FormData($('#frmCreate').get(0)); 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Experiment")',
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: formdata,         
            processData: false, 
            contentType: false
        });
    };

    $('#FileUpload').filer({

    //code omitted for brevity

    //Change 3: Comment out uploadFile section
    //uploadFile: { ... }

    });
<script>
```

***ViewModel:***

```
public class ExperimentViewModel
{
    //code omitted for brevity

    //Change 4
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> FileUpload { get; set; }
}
```

***Controller:***

```
public JsonResult Insert(ExperimentViewModel model) //Change 5
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //...   
    }
}
```