# MVC5 Razor input images to controller from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In my MVC application I try to add multiple image insert to my view where I have my `ViewModel` fields. So I would call my controller with one common button.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">                                  
     <div>
      <input id="fileupload" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files" />
     </div>
    </form>
     <div>
       .... some textbox etc. (InsertViewModel)
     </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-md-offset-8 col-md-10">
       <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
     </div>
    </div>
}
```

My controller looks:

```
 [HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Insert(InsertViewModel model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
 { ..... }
```

but allways I get count of my files object 0.

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC 4 Razor File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680629/mvc-4-razor-file-upload)

Comment: You should create the HTML Form using the `@Html.BeginForm` method

Comment: Specifically, in this case, `input type=file` is not of type `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>` so the default MVC binder does not bind to your parameter, leaving it empty.

Comment: So how can I change `input type=file` to `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>`?

Comment: You have nested forms which is invalid html (and the outer form without the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is being submitted) Remove it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please Add submit button into form and all text box also.
then it works fine.
Code For that is in View

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files" />
</div>
<div>
    <input id="name" type="text"  name="name" />
</div>
<div>
    <input id="address" type="text" name="address" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-8 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Hello

My Controller look like

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, Demo obj)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

[image: MultipleUploadFileBinded]

[image: ClassObjectBinded]

> And If You need two form in single view you can also send upload file and receive into controller using Request.Files

```
 if (Request.Files.Count > 0)//// Is image is uplaod by browse button
 {
               foreach(var fl in Request.Files)
               {
                    var inputStream = Request.Files[0].InputStream;
               }

  }
```

Like Above you can get stream of file and etc.

Comment: This is not addressing OP's issue - the problem is the invalid nested forms!

Comment: can have several <form> elements in one HTML page, you cannot nest them.

Comment: Yes, I know. And that's what OP's problem is - they have nested forms (`<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` is inside another form generated by `@using (Html.BeginForm())`) - all this answer says is to add a submit button which OP already had, and to add textboxes, which OP already had

Comment: you should either use @using (Html.BeginForm()) or <form> element

Comment: Yes I KNOW!! I'm the one writing the comments. You should edit your question to explain to the OP what the issue is