# Upload Files with ASP.NET and JMeter

Tags: c#, asp.net, jmeter

I'm new to ASP.NET but have some knowledge on using JMeter. My task is to create a web-service which accepts file uploaded via POST request.

My Controller

```
public class TestController : Controller {

    [HttpPost]
    public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file) {
        Logger.Debug("Upload Called, Request.Files.Count: " + Request.Files.Count);

        if(model.file != null)
            Logger.Debug("Okay");
        else
            Logger.Debug("Invalid file");

        return "done";
    }
}
```

My JMeter sampler
[JMeter HTTP request sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuA5w.png)
The `test.csv` file and my JMeter test plan are put under the same directory.

I however find the `file` variable is always `null`, and `Request.Files.Count` is always 0. Please help, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680629/mvc-4-razor-file-upload

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC 4 Razor File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680629/mvc-4-razor-file-upload)

Comment: Thanks first! I have checked that my JMeter request parameter name matches the controller's input parameter name, both called "file". Request.Files.Count is also found always 0, so I think the request contains no file. Would you please suggest my problem?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to mimic file upload request is just recording it using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder). See [Apache JMeter Proxy Step by Step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) manual for JMeter configuration instructions.

Just make sure your `test.csv` file is located in JMeter's "bin" folder during recording of the upload request, JMeter will automatically populate the relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler configuration. See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) guide for more details.

---

NB: don't forget to properly handle dynamic parameters like [VIEWSTATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I finally get a solution.

C# Controller

```
public class TestController : Controller {

    [HttpPost]
    public string Upload() {
        Logger.Debug("Upload Called, Request.Files.Count: " + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count);

        if(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            Logger.Debug("Okay");
        else
            Logger.Debug("Invalid file");

        return "done";
    }
}
```

Note that `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request` is used instead of `System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase`, and the JMeter sampler needs not to be changed.