# MVC 5 get path of the image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am creating a web app in which I am selecting an image from my drive from

```
<input class="file-upload-input" id="vattiuploadctrl" type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" accept="image/*" />
```

i just want to get full path of the particular image without saving the image,

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680629/mvc-4-razor-file-upload) if it helps

Comment: You want to get the path in the client machine ? Why do you need it ?

Comment: You cant (for security reasons). You can only get the file name. But why would you want the path anyway - that is completely irrelevant since you should never know the file structure on your users machines