# Files bigger than 4KB corrupted or empty uploading

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I implemented in my API a Controller to upload files with an `HTTP Post`request, nothing challenging from what you find on the web:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.GetMultipartBoundary()))
    {
        return StatusCode(415);
    }

    long size = Request.Form.Files.Sum(f => f.Length);

    var filePath =
        Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "TempUploads");

    string fileName = "";

    List<string> tempFileName = new List<string>();

    foreach (var formFile in Request.Form.Files)
    {
        fileName = formFile.FileName;
        string timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
        fileName = fileName.Replace(Path.GetExtension(formFile.FileName),
            timeStamp + Path.GetExtension(formFile.FileName));

        filePath = filePath + "\\" + fileName;
        if (formFile.Length > 0)
        {
            using(var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }

        tempFileName.Add(fileName);
    }

    return Ok(new { tempFileName });
}
```

It adds a `timeStamp` to the name, but I already tried without it and it doesn't change anything.

The problem I get is that if I upload files bigger than around `4KB` (still really small) they either are corrupted (won't open) or are empty (same amount of pages, but all blank) and weight a couple KB more.

Comment: Have you taking a look at https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/03/12/uploading-files-asp-net-core/? It has a pretty good walkthrough.

Comment: I'm not really in a situation where I need to stream, and the buffering version is not very complete, plus I've searched everywhere and they all implement it the way I did but can upload large files.

Comment: I'll delete my answer as it is patently wrong. Sorry @Rep

Comment: No problem, thanks for your time

Comment: You could try declaring your filename inside the foreach block as I think the filename will change while still processing when there is more than one file being uploaded

Comment: I'm wondering if there is an issue with your function prototype. I went through a couple of projects I have with file uploads and noticed all of them have a parameter `List<IFormFile> files`. You may want to try `public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files)` rather than pulling them from the Request object.

Comment: Yeah, most examples do it like that, I didn't at first because for some reason using PostMan it doesn't work getting the file like that, however in one of all the tests I did I tried creating a view for the api to do the request and I implemented it like you suggested and got the same result

Comment: Is it possible the problem is external to the controller (client, etc)? Have you tried a non-async version like https://stackoverflow.com/a/15680783/1237135 to see if that works OK?

Comment: I just tried non async and checked my view as the link suggested, but nothing changed. I doubt it is how i get the file the problem

Comment: How big are the files you're trying to upload? And are you using IIS for hosting?

Comment: I have one that is 3KB and uploads perfectly fine, then I have one of 8KB which doesn't..

Comment: The only thing I can think of besides the client not sending it properly is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698350/increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core but by default that shouldn't be the issue for an 8kb file

Answer (score 0):

Just found out what was the problem in my particular case, I was using a Middleware for logging and request handling and that for some reason affects the request, if I disable the Middleware it uploads perfectly.