# A public action method 'InternalServerError' was not found on controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, razor, c#-4.0

I try to upload file using form but when I add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form
it have problem `A public action method InternalServerError was not found on controller`
when I remove it is ok but no have file send from view to controller how. how can I solve it

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the form action attribute value are correct. `action was not found on controller` may cause by url wrong.

You can refer to this question. [MVC 4 Razor File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680629/mvc-4-razor-file-upload)